# Matplotlib Python -> Plot_dendrogram Axis object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm building a `plot_dendrogram` graph and I'm struggling with the axis object. I need to create a Matplotlib axis object from 0,0.5 for the x and y axis. How do I do this?

current attempt:

```
plt.axis([0,.5,0,.5])
```

and I get the following error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'set_ylim'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis) states, `plt.axis` is a convenience function, which sets the axis limits of the *current axes* object.

To create the axes object, I would suggest something like this:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([0, 0.5])
ax.set_ylim([0, 0.5])
```

However, I'm not sure how you got the error you posted. Even if I have not created any axes and just do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.axis([0,.5,0,.5])
```

I don't get an error.